# \begin{document} ended by \end{figure}, latex error in thesis template

Tags: pstricks, thesis

I am writing a thesis in latex, when I add the pstricks code it runs but when I insert the `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` command to caption the figure, it generates error
`\begin{document}` ended by `\end{figure}`...

These are the packages I am using.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
 \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{xthesis} %DAL Thesis Style
\usepackage{xtocinc} %Include Table of Contents as the first entry in TOC
%                    Advanced Studies and Research Board insists on this!?
 \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
 \usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
  \usepackage{epsfig}
  \usepackage{pstricks-add}
 \usepackage{pst-blur}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphics, tikz}
\hfuzz2pt % Don't bother to report over-full boxes if over-edge is < 2pt
% Line spacing -----------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\defbaselineskip}
\setlength{\defbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\setlinespacing}[1]%
           {\setlength{\baselineskip}{#1 \defbaselineskip}}
\newcommand{\doublespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}%
                           {2.0 \defbaselineskip}}
\newcommand{\singlespacing}{\setlength{\baselineskip}{\defbaselineskip}}
% MATH -------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\A}{{\cal A}}
\newcommand{\h}{{\cal H}}
\newcommand{\s}{{\cal S}}
\newcommand{\W}{{\cal W}}
\newcommand{\BH}{\mathbf B(\cal H)}
\newcommand{\KH}{\cal K(\cal H)}
\newcommand{\Real}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\Complex}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\Field}{\mathbb F}
\newcommand{\RPlus}{[0,\infty)}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\essnorm}[1]{\norm{#1}_{\text{\rm\normalshape}}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\seq}[1]{\left<#1\right>}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\To}{\longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\RE}{\operatorname{Re}}
\newcommand{\IM}{\operatorname{Im}}
\newcommand{\Poly}{{\cal{P}}(E)}
\newcommand{\EssD}{{\cal{D}}}
% THEOREMS ---------------------------------------------------------------
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
%
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
%
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
%
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
%%% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\tclineskip}{1.05\baselineskip}
%%% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\def\ZZ{Z\!\!\!Z}
\begin{document}
%\nobib
%\draft
%\nofront
%\permissionfalse
\dedicate{\textit{Dedications\\ To my Parents\\
and\\ those who taught me even a single word\\ in my life.}}
\nolistoftables \nolistoffigures \msc \copyrightyear{2013}

\submitdate{September, 2013}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{}

\author{}

\supervisor{}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
\typeout{:?0000} % Don't bother with over/under-full boxes
%\beforepreface
\typeout{:?1111} % Process All Errors from Here on
}

\setlinespacing{2}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
{\typeout{Introduction} \markright{\it Ch 1: Introduction}
\include{T0}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setlinespacing{2}
\setlinespacing{1.5} \markright{\it References}
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
%\bibliography{XBib}
%\appendix
%\include{Appendix}
\end{document}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This the code of my chapter in which i have added the figure

```
\def\baselinestretch{1}
\chapter{Introduction}
\def\baselinestretch{1.66}
%%% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\goodbreak
\begin{figure}
\scalebox{1} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,-1.6045313)(2.64,1.6045313)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.0,0.94609374)(2.62,-1.0739063)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.62,0.18609375)(0.96,0.18609375)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.96,0.22609375)(0.84,0.56609374)
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(0.17078125,1.4360938){P}
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(2.1767187,-1.3839062){Q}
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{b}{it}
\rput(2.0196874,0.13609375){x}
\end{pspicture}
}\end{figure}
```

This file generates the error. If i remove \begin{figure} and \end{figure} it works.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: the most likely cause is that you have an `\end{figure}` without a `\begin{figure}` but it is hard to debug that if you only show a part of your document that is unrelated to the error.

Comment: why???? are you loading `newlfont` this century? unless you particularly need to make font commands work like nfss-latex2.09 that was distributed around 1991-2 before latex2e was published. why load pstricks twice and why load epsfig at all (again unless you are emulating a document from 1990)

Comment: This is the file of my chapter

Comment: \def\baselinestretch{1}
\chapter{Introduction}
\def\baselinestretch{1.66}
\goodbreak
\section{Curve}
\begin{figure}
\scalebox{1} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,-1.6045313)(2.64,1.6045313)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.0,0.94609374)(2.62,-1.0739063)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.62,0.18609375)(0.96,0.18609375)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.96,0.22609375)(0.84,0.56609374)
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(0.17078125,1.4360938){P}
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\rput(2.1767187,-1.3839062){Q}
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{b}{it}
\rput(2.0196874,0.13609375){x}
\end{pspicture}
}\end{figure}

Comment: don't add code in comments you can edit the question to fix the example, it should start `\documentclass` and end `\end{docuemnt}` and _produce the error message that you are asking about_ `. start from a copy of your document and delete everything that you can delete while still having the error.

Comment: I have posted the code it generates the same error

Comment: I do not know `xthesis` and `xtocinc`. What are they? Are they needed here? I am installing like the tenth package right now in order to compile your code. Please try to reduce (finished... does not compile). Where do you have this template from, it uses plain-TeX syntax.

Comment: I am using this template to the thesis.

Comment: Just a wild guess: `endfloat` is included from one of the packages, and since `\end{figure}` does not stand in a line on its own, it won't be recognized by `endfloat`. If this is the case the solution is simple: Always put `\end{figure}` on a line on its own. Do not use something like `}\end{figure}` (on one line), use `}` and `\end{figure}` (on two lines) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am using package `setspace`for the vertical spacing. THis works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
%\usepackage{xthesis} %DAL Thesis Style
%\usepackage{xtocinc} %Include Table of Contents as the first entry in TOC
%                    Advanced Studies and Research Board insists on this!?
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx, tikz}
\hfuzz2pt % Don't bother to report over-full boxes if over-edge is < 2pt
% Line spacing -----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{setspace}
\newcommand{\A}{{\cal A}}
\newcommand{\h}{{\cal H}}
\newcommand{\s}{{\cal S}}
\newcommand{\W}{{\cal W}}
\newcommand{\BH}{\mathbf B(\cal H)}
\newcommand{\KH}{\cal K(\cal H)}
\newcommand{\Real}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\Complex}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\Field}{\mathbb F}
\newcommand{\RPlus}{[0,\infty)}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\essnorm}[1]{\norm{#1}_{\text{\rm\normalshape}}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\seq}[1]{\left<#1\right>}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\To}{\longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\RE}{\operatorname{Re}}
\newcommand{\IM}{\operatorname{Im}}
\newcommand{\Poly}{{\cal{P}}(E)}
\newcommand{\EssD}{{\cal{D}}}
% THEOREMS ---------------------------------------------------------------
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
%
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
%
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
%
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\def\ZZ{Z\!\!\!Z}
\begin{document}
%   \dedicate{\textit{Dedications\\ To my Parents\\
%           and\\ those who taught me even a single word\\ in my life.}}
%   \nolistoftables \nolistoffigures \msc \copyrightyear{2013}
%   \submitdate{September, 2013}
    \title{}
    \author{}
%   \supervisor{}
%   \setspace{2}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\markright{\itshape Ch 1: Introduction}
\singlespacing
\chapter{Introduction}
\setstretch{1.66}       \goodbreak
\begin{figure}\centering
\psscalebox{1} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
        {%
            \begin{pspicture}(0,-1.6045313)(2.64,1.6045313)
            \psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.0,0.94609374)(2.62,-1.0739063)
            \psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.62,0.18609375)(0.96,0.18609375)
            \psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.96,0.22609375)(0.84,0.56609374)
            \usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
            \rput(0.17078125,1.4360938){P}
            \usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
            \rput(2.1767187,-1.3839062){Q}
            \usefont{T1}{ptm}{b}{it}
            \rput(2.0196874,0.13609375){x}
            \end{pspicture}%
}
\end{figure}
\setstretch{1.5} \markright{\it References}
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But it is not running the dedication command

Comment: When i enable the xthesis package it again shows the same error.

Comment: is this package available for download?

Comment: `xthesis` seems to be a LaTeX 2.09 package which redefines `\@xfloat` in a way incompatible to the current LaTeX2e implementation!?